# how to draw a circle with initial degree and turn it around with the code and move it?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, drawing, geometry

I would like to draw a circle with an initial degree and I want to round the circle around itself at some degree by clicking on buttons and then move it at that degree direction. If you look at the picture bottom, you can understand better.

[image]

White line shows the current degree and imagine that there are 3 buttons in the name of (+) (-) and (move) . When I click on (+) it will increase the degree with some number, when I click on (-), it will decrease the degree with some number. when I click on (move), circle will start to move at current degree like red line on the picture.

How can it be done ? 
Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformations 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx 
This is a sample using transform in code behind 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754009.aspx

If you want it to move in a smooth manner then animation is the tool